# How to get a list of all components on the Form at Design-Time?

Tags: delphi, ide, components, design-time

I need to get a list of all components on the Form at Design-Time (not controls, just components).

The components must also be visible on the Form as a 24x24 image at Design-Time.

I could use code like this

```
procedure TForm2.GetComponentList(Memo1: TMemo)
var
  i: Integer;
begin
 for i := 0 to ComponentCount-1 do
   if (Components[i] is TComponent) and not (Components[i] is TControl) then
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Components[i].Name);
end;
```

but here I will get invisible components like TField etc.

I need only components that the IDE show on the Form as a 24x24 bitmap.

May be I can use Open Tools API?

Comment: You could check how [GExperts](http://www.gexperts.org/) do it - see http://sourceforge.net/p/gexperts/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/Source/Experts/GX_HideNonVisualComps.pas.

Comment: @Uli, except that GExperts is working with and manipulating the UI elements in the IDE (instances of the 'TContainer' WNDCLASS), which is not the same thing as identifying the **TComponents** that those IDE UI elements represent on the form (what the OP is asking for).  The GExperts approach is entirely useless for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non-visual components created as part of other components (e.g. a **TField** within a **TDataSet** etc) are children of the containing component.  This relationship is apparent in the DFM - if viewed as text you will see that the field components are children of the corresponding dataset object.

Non-visual components that are placed on the form directly (e.g. the TDataset's themselves) are children of the form object:

```
object frmMain: TfrmMain
  ...
  object MyClientDataSet: TClientDataSet
    ...
    object MyClientDataSetID: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'id'
    end
    object MyClientDataSetTitle: TStringField
      FieldName = 'title'
      Size = 255
    end
  end
  object MyDataSource: TDataSource
    DataSet = MyClientDataSet
    Left = 488
    Top = 120
  end
end
```

Even though there is no visual parent/child relationship between non-visual components, non-visual components never-the-less do know whether or not they have a parent.

This is accessible via the **HasParent** property of a **TComponent**.

Crucially however, a **Form** is *not* considered to be the parent of *directly* placed non-visual components.

Therefore, if **HasParent** is **FALSE** for a non-visual component on a form (an item in **Form.Components**) then it is a directly placed component, not a child of some other component.

Simply modify your **if** condition as follows:

```
if (NOT (Components[i] is TControl)) and (NOT Components[i].HasParent) then
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Components[i].Name);
```

Note that I have removed the test for **is TComponent** since this is *always* going to be *TRUE* for an item in the **Components** property of a form.

Comment: I guess the question then is why the code in the question isn't sufficient.

Comment: Yes, I realised that myself... the form always owns all components placed on it.  I was this close to the answer (holds fingers up almost pressed together)... there is no difference in the relationships in the DFM - for visual or non-visual, a child component has a parent.  There is a subtle twist however, and this can be used to detect the non-visual 'root' components on a form.  I have revised the answer accordingly, complete with suggested code change to achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: That's a lot better now